# Pandas text similarity between a list and pd.DataFrame column

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

I have a `pd.DataFrame (named df_sim)`as given below (it is a sample only)

**Edit**

```
Type                                     Sent
icro soft student advantage      why should i connect to vpn
Microsoft Student Advantage      why should i connect to vpn
the V  P  N                      why should i connect to vpn
the V PN                         why should i connect to vpn
my laundry bucks                 why should i connect to vpn
CSI                              why should i connect to vpn
```

My objective is to find the most similar 'Type' from the given 'Sent'. 
I am performing cosine similarity and the necessary codes are as follows.

```
df_sim['Type'] = df_sim['Type'].apply(lambda x : re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]',' ',x))
vect = TfIdfVectorizer()
vect.fit(df['Type'] +" " +df['Sent'])
A = vect.transform(df['Type'])
B = vect.transform(df['Sent'])
sim = paired_cosine_distances(A,B)  #from from sklearn.metrics.pairwise 
                                    import paired_cosine_distances
y = df_sim.iloc[np.argmin(sim)]['Type']
```

I was expecting `np.argmin(sim)` to be 2 or 3 and thus y is `'the V PN' or 'the V P N'`. Instead I am getting np.argmin(sim) to be 5 with y being CSI
With this, I have two questions:

1. Should I at all use cosine similarity measures? can regex like stuff will do the needful?
2. Why I am not getting the correct phrase in 'Type' column. In many cases the above technique is working, but here it is not. Why?

Comment: You mentioned similarity from a list, is there a certain column value you want to get the highest similarity by?

Comment: if `vect` is `CountVectorizer`, or other vectorizer that tokenizes on the regex `\w+`, the tokens that you are creating when vectorizing two series separately, variables `A` and `B`, have no components which are, simultaneously, different than zero. Their cosine similarity should therefore be zero, for all of the pairs of vectors. Please post the full code, including the tokenizer function and the description of the vectorizer you are using, to get a better answer

Comment: 'vect' is 'TfidfVectorizer()' I have not used any regex. I have edited the question above and given the few more lines which are necessary.

Comment: @BernardL: Technically in the question I have the word VPN, so intuitively, so `y` should be either 'the V PN` or `the V P N`.

Comment: @pythondumb I think intuitively in this sense is too broad of an assumption to be made. Imagine a spelling corrector that has no reference to what it is supposed to be corrected too.